# Cartesian Product on column headers for Time Series Data

Tags: r

Say I had a dataframe like

```
d <- c("03-12-2018","03-11-2018")
g <- c(10,5)
p <- c(8,9)
a <- c(7,2)
df <- data.frame(d,g,p,a)
colnames(df) <- c("date","grapes","pears","apples")

df
        date grapes pears apples
1 03-12-2018     10     8      7
2 03-11-2018      5     9      2
```

I essentially want output looking like:

```
date        grapes_pears    grapes_apples    pears_apples
3-12-2018   2               3                1    
3-11-2018   -4              3                7
```

So the values in the output table are just the difference between the first fruit and the second fruit in the column. A basic Cartesian product on the headers (ex date column) is fine... I know I will receive pairs in reverse (grapes_pears, pears_grapes) and simply a sign change for the value and also cases with grapes_grapes but for now that is okay. Will refine later.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `combn()`, i.e.

```
combn(names(df[-1]),2, FUN = function(i) Reduce(`-`, df[i]))
```

which gives,

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]    2    3    1
> [2,]   -4    3    7
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sotos... What if i want the reverses of each fruit and not to have the data filtered down

Comment: If you want the reverse just use `rev(df[-1])`. As for the filtering down I m not sure what you mean

Comment: Sorry, so i meant I want to return: grapes_pears, grapes_apples, pears_apples, pears_grapes, apples_grapes, apples_pears, grapes_grapes, apples_apples, pears_pears

I dont care what order they are in fwiw

Comment: Well, If we name the above matrix `m1` then the reverse would just be `-m1` so something like `cbind(m1, -m1)` would do it